# Nested attributes not saving in database? Does not display values - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-attributes

I have a nested attribute and I can display values, but it is not saving into database why?

I have a model `review` and I want to nest attribute `comments`

**review migration file**

```
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :reviews, [:reviewable_id, :reviewable_type]

  end
end
```

**review model**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :rating, :user_id, :comments_attributes, :service
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments

end
```

**comments migration file**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :comments, [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
  end
end
```

**comment model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :review
end
```

**This is the form**

```
<%= form_for [@reviewable, @review], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :comments, @review.comments.build do |field| %>
    <%= field.label "Comment" %></div>
    <%= field.text_field :content %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It displays the fields, but how come when I save, it doesn't save?

I tried to display like this:

```
<%= @review.comments %>
```

Here's my review controller

```
  def new
    @review = @reviewable.reviews.new
    @review.comments.build
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

**Review controller: create method**

```
  def create
    @review = @reviewable.reviews.new(params[:review])
    @review.user = current_user
    if @review.save
      redirect_to @reviewable, notice: "review created."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please post the `create` method in your controller

Comment: @muttonlamb Hello! I have edited my post to include the create method. Is there anything wrong with it? Thanks!

Comment: I cant see any problem there. could you share your code if possible, I mean using any public repo?

Comment: you can also try to inspect the log, whats happening there, is there any comment created when you save review?

Comment: @Muntasim It seems like it is being committed into the database, but it doesn't save into reviews database, from my log it there's a `insert into "reviews"` and another `insert into "comments"`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some muddled logic in your controller and views

```
  def new
    @review = @reviewable.reviews.new
    @review.comments.build
  end
```

Here you are calling `@reviewable.reviews.new`, but `@reviewable` doesn't yet exist.  A more usual way of calling this would be `Review.new`

Next in your view you do this

```
<%= form_for [@reviewable, @review], :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :comments, @review.comments.build do |field| %>
```

This is passing `@reviewable` and `@review` to the `form_for`.  This seems odd.  With nesting you would normally only need to pass the top level instance variable i.e. `@review`.

Next, when you get to `fields_for` you are passing `:comments` and `@review.comments.build`.  Generally speaking this should only require `:comment`, because you've already built the comment in the controller.

I would recommend that you review these two screencasts

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

There are also a number of Gems that handle the whole process of making things commentable very eloquently, they can be found here

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_comments

I think the commentable Gems path is better because they are being worked on by a larger community and I think end up being better than personal creations in the long term.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

you need to replace the following

```
<%= f.fields_for :comments, @review.comments.build do |field| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :comments, @review.comments do |field| %>
```

to see created comments in form. As you have `@review.comments.build` in new action. Otherwise you cant see the associated comments on editing review

Comment: If I remove the .build, then the field for comments disappears

Comment: you have to have `@review.comments.build` in new action as I mentioned  and in edit action `@review.comments.build if  @review.comments.empty?`

Comment: I do have @review.comments.build in new action (I didn't touch my previous code, which has it in there). I also added the last bits into edit action, same result. The field does not show up. Also, I forgot to mention but not sure if it matters.. This form is in `views/reviews/_form.html.erb`, but I have rendered this page inside `views/users/reviews.html.erb`